# String to resources path converter

Tags: android, string, resources, converters

I can't find in my books if there is way to convert string to resources path in android development.
For example:

```
String path = "R.raw.mediaFile";
MediaPlayer myPlayer;
myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, ***<Some Expression>(path)***);
```

Please provide a short example.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're after

```
context.getResources().getIndentifier(...)
```

Converts a String reference to the int value. See here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Another useful method once you've got the id is

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
```

You can set this as a datasource for the media player

```
myPlayer.setDatasource(aft.getFileDescriptor())
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick and detailed answer!